# How to convert JS function to Typescript when it has class-like variables inside of it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting a codebase to typescript and I've run into something that I have never seen before. I'm converting two functions which seem to have class-like variables in them. One of the functions in question look like this:

```js
const wait = (ms) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            delete wait.reject;
            resolve();
        }, ms);

        wait.reject = (reason) => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            reject(reason);
        };
    });
```

As you can see, it has a variable within it called `wait.reject` which is an arrow function that is defined at the bottom. At the top, the reject variable is deleted after a certain period of time.

To type this, I have had to resort to writing `(wait as { reject: ... }.reject` as you can see below:

```js
const wait = (ms: number) =>
    new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            delete (wait as { reject?: () => void }).reject;
            resolve();
        }, ms);

        (wait as { reject?: (reason: string) => void }).reject = (reason: string) => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            reject(reason);
        };
    });
```

Of course, using `as` is far from ideal. Does anybody know how to type this correctly? There is more than one function in the codebase that has this problem.

Please and thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I would **strongly** recommend not having the `wait` function work the way it works in that code. What if you make two calls to `wait`? Then you have the second `reject` overwriting the first `reject`. Perhaps consider having the function return an object with `promise` and `reject` properties, so the consumer of the function can manage them. (Example at the end of the answer.) Of course, if you're adding types to an existing codebase you may not be able to refactor right now (but one of the great things about TypeScript, IMHO, is how much it helps when you *do* have time to refactor).

But to the types:

Your `wait` function is a function accepting a `number` parameter and returning `Promise<void>`, which also has an optional `reject` property which is a function which accepts an `any` parameter and returns `void`. (Note: That's not a "class-like variable," it's an object property. All functions are objects in JavaScript and TypeScript.) You write that type with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) (`&`) of a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html) and an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) with an optional `reject` property:

```typescript
type WaitFn = ((ms: number) => Promise<void>) & { reject?: (reason: any) => void };
```

Then use that type on `wait`:

```typescript
const wait: WaitFn = (ms: number) =>
//        ^^^^^^^^
    new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            delete wait.reject;
            resolve();
        }, ms);

        wait.reject = (reason) => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            reject(reason);
        };
    });
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6ghgS2AMQHZQLxQBTYLYDOAXFKgK54BGEATgJSYB8UACjQPZ4IEQA8AbuwQATRgwBkUAN5QaEAFYQAxsAD8JbHLgF2qEnFQgGGZoJFQAvgG4AUDaW6CwKAHdEwEvCRpMOQiXIqWmNGGyhw0ggXVg4uHgEhUVw5HQAbfggAGlkFZWAQ6TCI4odUJyhgBDwIdjJgAElhXx5gABUqmrrcAqki4v6oYQhUiGBoNyQAOjlFFVsBgZT2dIhsOnmFi2zCdbsF13dp3JVfTQhtXR6+-aglEbgadura4GxK57rG3ZuImbyzi6ob6bDbhCy7IA)

In the above, I also added a type annotation on `ms` (`ms: number`) and a type argument (`<void>`) to `new Promise`, but you don't actually have to, you can allow those types to be inferred from `WaitFn` if you like. Here I've removed them:

```typescript
const wait: WaitFn = (ms) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            delete wait.reject;
            resolve();
        }, ms);

        wait.reject = (reason) => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            reject(reason);
        };
    });
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6ghgS2AMQHZQLxQBTYLYDOAXFKgK54BGEATgJSYB8UACjQPZ4IEQA8AbuwQATRgwBkUAN5QaEAFYQAxsAD8JbHLgF2qEnFQgGGZoJFQAvgG4AUDaW6CwKAHdEwEvCRpMOQscYbKGDSCBdWDi4eXDkdABt+CAAaWQVlYADpIJCch1QnKGAEPAh2MmAASWFfHmAAFWLS8txMqWycjqhhCDiIYGg3JAA6OUUVW07O2PYEiGw6CcmLFP9bdo7B4BG0lV9NCG1dVvXJqCVeuBoGkrLgbCKb8qqFk8nR9P3D1BfT63WLF5AA)

---

But as I said at the top, I wouldn't write `wait` that way, because two overlapping calls to it have cross-talk — the function ends up with the second `reject` on it.

Instead, I'd probably return an object with `promise` and `reject` members:

```typescript
const wait = (ms: number) => {
    let promiseReject: (reason: any) => void;
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
    const promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, _reject) => {
        promiseReject = _reject;
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    });
    let reject = (reason: any) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        promiseReject(reason);
    };
    return { promise, reject };
};
```

You'd use it by receiving those, then waiting for the promise, calling `reject` if appropriate:

```
const { promise, reject } = wait(1000);
// ...
```